# How to create a data model to support selection over multiple partition and sort key values in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, data-modeling

The scenario is I have many `groups` with a `score` in many `categories` for each `day`.

I need to get `scores` for all `groups` in a list for all `categories` in a list, between two given days.

In SQL this would look something like `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE group IN [...] AND category IN [...] AND date < ? AND date > ?;`

I came up with the following but I can only elegantly query by a single group or by a single category

```
pk         | sk              |
-----------------------------
group-name | category + date | score
```

What what be a good way to model this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible in DynamoDB in a single-query. You would have to query by a single group or by a single category.

But maybe for a better performance you should specify the sk as `date + category`. This way you can query the table for each group in the list with a KeyConditions for the sk between the date range and a Filter Condition using IN clause for the category.